# How can I save multiple html outputs from python into a single file (or multiple)?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

Thanks to the help of a stackoverflow user I managed to get a for loop working to clean the HTML in a series of URLs. Here is my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re

allpages = ["https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-1.html", "https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-2.html", "https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-3.html", "https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-4.html", "https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-5.html", "https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-6.html", "https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-7.html", "https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-8.html", "https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-9.html", "https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-10.html", "https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-11.html"]

for i in allpages:
     page = urlopen(i)
     html_bytes = page.read()
     html = html_bytes.decode("utf-8")
     start_index = html.find("</div><!-- END: Top Songs -->")
     end_index = html.find("</div><!-- END: lyrics -->")
     clean = html[start_index:end_index]
     print(clean)

saveFile = open('bdall.html', 'w')
saveFile.write(clean)
saveFile.close()
```

Now, when I arrive at saving the file, only the last URL in my list (11) is saved as an html file. How can I alter the save command to create html files for all of the URLs?

Comment: your code saved only last url, as you are creating the file at the end of the loop. you can move your save file in the loop or better would be, keep HTML in a list, and once all the htmls are collected, write the list data(htmls) to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the results into a list and then write the list to a file.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re

allpages = ["https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-1.html", "https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-2.html", "https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-3.html", "https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-4.html", "https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-5.html", "https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-6.html", "https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-7.html", "https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-8.html", "https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-9.html", "https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-10.html", "https://www.metrolyrics.com/bob-dylan-alpage-11.html"]

scrapped_list = []

for i in allpages:
     print(i)
     page = urlopen(i)
     html_bytes = page.read()
     html = html_bytes.decode("utf-8")
     start_index = html.find("</div><!-- END: Top Songs -->")
     end_index = html.find("</div><!-- END: lyrics -->")
     clean = html[start_index:end_index]
     scrapped_list.append(clean)

MyFile=open('output.txt','w', encoding='utf-8')
for lyrics in scrapped_list:
     MyFile.write(lyrics)
MyFile.close()
```

Comment: Joe, you're an absolute king for this one. Thank you man

Comment: If I answered your question, please up vote it and mark it as closed. Always glad to help. also take a look at beautifulsoup for more scraping.

Comment: Fair enough! Thanks for closing the question.

Comment: looks like I just reached the required rep. Thanks again, and yes I will be becoming more familiar with bs4